# UIPickerView custom view strange behavior

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

I have a problem with UIPickerView...

I created a UIPickerView with two components with two rows for the first one, and three rows for the second one.
I'm trying to create a custom view for each row in each component. Okay, I've subclassed UIView and added one UIImageView and one UILabel.

I've used the `- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view` method to create the custom view and it seems to work ok.

But when each row "enters" the middle area of the UIPickerView, all the content disappears!

Here's an image:
[image]

Anyone with ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and found the solution on stackoverflow-but I can't find the link, so I included the code below. to be clear-I am not claiming this code as my own. If anyone finds the original answer, vote their answer up

```
// self.myImages is an array of UIImageView objects
UIView * myView = [self.myImages objectAtIndex:row];

// first convert to a UIImage
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.bounds.size, NO, 0);

[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// then convert back to a UIImageView and return it
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

return imageView;
```